# reactjs - having some issues with my functions to update state and using promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs

basically, I am validating form fields by checking if they pass my regex, and if they do, I am setting state with either 'success' or 'error' (used by react-bootstrap).

so basically, I have about 6 functions that need to execute, however, the password field validation functions are giving me a lot of trouble.

My `handleSubmit()` at the moment looks something like this -

```
handleSubmit() {
  this.validate1();
  this.validate2();
  // ...
  this.validatePassword();
  this.validateConfirmPassword();
}
```

However, the issue is that `validatePassword()` will setState either 'success' or 'error', and since the functions are not firing off in order, I usually get the wrong result for `validateConfirmPassword()`.

I am reading the mozilla page on Promises, but I am really confused and not sure how to apply that in my code.

Could I do something like `Promise.all([everything_except_validateConfirmPassword]).then(validateConfirmPassword())` but that doesn't seem right..

```
validatePassword(pass) {
    if (pass.length >= 8) {
      if (checkPass.test(pass)) {
        this.setState({
          passValidation: validation.success
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          passValidation: validation.error
        });
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({
        passValidation: validation.error
      });
    }
  }

validateConfirmPassword(pass, confirmPass) {
    const matches = pass === confirmPass;
    if (matches && this.state.passValidation === validation.success) {
      this.setState({
        confirmPassValidation: validation.success
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        confirmPassValidation: validation.error
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are any of these functions asynchronous?

Comment: hello.  yeah - all of them right now, but I am wondering how I can get `validateConfirmPassword()` to fire after `validatePassword()`

Comment: ...are you sure?  Checking strings against some regular expression isn't asynchronous.  Unless you are talking to a server and waiting for a response, you don't really need Promises.

Comment: sorry.  I am not talking to a server, just running regex checks.  Please allow me a moment to update my question with the two functions in question.

Comment: does your `validatePassword` have `this.setState` method ?

Comment: Hi.  I updated the question with code.  Thx !

Comment: @PhiNguyen The question is not about the inability to use `setState`, but rather its asynchronous nature which doesn't guarantee that the component's state is set before it is consumed by another function.

Comment: OP - why are you saving `passValidation` in state?  Is it only so your `validateConfirmPassword` function can use it, or is there another reason?

Comment: passValidation lets the user know the reason why their password failed, whereas passConfirmValidation lets the user know if their passwords don't match if their passValidation passes

Comment: the validation states are either 'warning', 'error', or 'success', and they are used in my styling/hint messages.

Comment: oh crap guys.  i am so sorry... i made a mistake in my code.  really sorry about this.  should i delete my code?  i am doing my check wrong :/

Comment: @MichaelParker The problem is that he couldn't get the last updated state for the next function. The reason is because `this.setState` is async.

Comment: @PhiNguyen - Yes, that is exactly what I said in a previous comment.

Comment: @MichaelParker Opps. Sorry for my inconsideration. =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can solve this by using React's `componentDidUpdate` in this way:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.canCheckConfirmPwd) {
    this.validateConfirmPassword();
  }
}

validatePassword(pass) {
if (pass.length >= 8) {
  if (checkPass.test(pass)) {
    this.setState({
      passValidation: validation.success,
      canCheckConfirmPwd: true, // on next update we'll trigger validateConfirmPassword()
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      passValidation: validation.error
    });
  }
} else {
  this.setState({
    passValidation: validation.error
  });
  }
}

validateConfirmPassword(pass, confirmPass) {
    const matches = pass === confirmPass;
    if (matches && this.state.passValidation === validation.success) {
      this.setState({
        confirmPassValidation: validation.success,
        canCheckConfirmPwd: false, // to avoid retriggering the function on next update
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        confirmPassValidation: validation.error,
        canCheckConfirmPwd: false,
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you.  unfortunately i had a code error and it was 100% my fault :(  i am sorry

Comment: This answer re-enforces OP's excessive use of state in his component.  Ideally, you should keep state as minimal as possible.  Please take a look at [this article](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/09/common-react-dot-js-mistakes-unneeded-state/) to help understand why.

Comment: what would be a better way to do this then?  i am open to suggestions!  :)

Comment: I would personally put in the state just two fields, `validFields` and `invalidFields`. Each of them would be an array of strings. And then in componentDidUpdate you could use a check like `if (this.state.validFields.includes('password') && !this.state.validFields.includes('confirmPassword') && !this.state.invalidFields.includes('confirmPassword'))` instead of the current check `(this.state.canCheckConfirmPwd)`. The idea is that you know you still have to check confirmPassword if this is not in `validFields` and not in `invalidFields` while password is actually in `validFields`.